# CodeIgniter: Input class not being loaded (or so I think)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to work with the CI framework (PHP), and not having much luck with the core "Input" class.

Here's my code:

```
$user_name = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
```

This is the result when I try to load the controller:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Login::$input
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 24

Any Tips?

Comment: Since it says "This class is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually." in the documentation of Input class, that should not be the problem. Is your controller extending the controller baseclass? Maybe you can show us the whole class with all other methods removed except for the one containing this code?

Comment: Did you call the parent constructor in your controllers constructor?  Are your system and application paths set correctly in config.php?  What else is in your controller, and which version of ci?

Comment: I didn't call the constructor...didn't realize I had to if I was extending the parent CI_Controller class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure that your controller extends `CI_Controller` and that you call the parent constructor in your own:

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /* the rest of your code... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I needed to use the constructor function and then call the parent...just thought extending the CI_Controller function was enough.